# Orbits of action, why are they interesting?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ a group, $X$ a $G-$set under the action $\cdot :G\times X\to X$. So, I know the definition of an action, but I don't understand which information the give us. For example, if $G=SL_2(\mathbb R)$ and $X=\hat{\mathbb C}=\mathbb C\cup\{\infty \}$, we have that
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}\cdot z=\begin{cases}\frac{az+b}{cz+d}&cz+d\neq 0\\\infty &cz+d=0\\ \frac{a}{c}&z=\infty ,\ c=0\\ \infty &z=\infty ,\ c\neq 0.\end{cases}$$

So, I know that the orbits are $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \Im(z)>0\}$, $\{z\in \mathbb C\mid \Im(z)<0\}$ and $\hat{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup\{\infty \}$.

Know, what does this mean ? How can I interpret it ? That the action separate $\hat{\mathbb C}$ in 3 part ?

Comment: Do you know that any $G$-set is the disjoint union of its orbits?

Comment: @Rick: Yes, sure. And so ?

Comment: You already have the orbit which are three, what Rick is trying to tell you is that in this case $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is the disjoint union of these three orbits.

Comment: But acctually, it can be disjoint union of many other things... so, why orbits are interesting ?

Comment: If your object of interest natural lives in $X$ and is symmetric with respect to $SL_2 (\mathbb{R})$ the orbits tell you which part of the objects are naturally identified by the symmetry. For example, how do you know which parts of a (5-pointed) starfish are the same on each limb? It's the parts that are in the same position up to a rotation by a multiple of $2\pi/5$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins: what do you mean by "symmetric with respect to $SL_2(\mathbb R)$" ?

Comment: Acting on the object by $SL_2 (\mathbb{R})$ returns the same object as far as you, the mathematician, have decided to care. A star fish stays the same after we rotate it by $2\pi/5$ (okay I'm not a biologist, but hopefully the picture is clear). The point is that we naturally identify parts of the starfish that are on the same part of each leg, i.e. in the same orbit of $C_5$ (the cyclic group on $5$ elements).

Comment: This is mobius transformation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that the upper half-plane is a full orbit of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ is really the first step in several directions.  For example, the action of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ on the upper half-plane gives *isometries* for the hyperbolic metric on the upper half-plane. Being able to get from anywhere to anywhere else in the upper half-plane by a matrix in ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ is roughly analogous to being able to get from anywhere to anywhere in $\mathbf R^2$ by translations. (There's a bit more going on, but I did say "roughly".) If you were going to do something geometric in $\mathbf R^2$, isn't it convenient to be able to set the "origin" anywhere you want? Anyone who is doing geometry in the hyperbolic plane finds it equally convenient that the upper half-plane is a single orbit for ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$.

What you know about the orbit of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ can be fruitfully combined
with knowing the stabilizer subgroup of some point. A nice number to pick is $i$: its stabilizer subgroup is ${\rm SO}_2(\mathbf R)$. (Fun fact: the  orbits of ${\rm SO}_2(\mathbf R)$ on the upper half-plane are the circles in the upper half-plane centered at $i$ for the hyperbolic metric on the upper half-plane, so $i$ as a hyperbolic center of a circle is not in the same place as the Euclidean center of those circles). Therefore the upper half-plane can be regarded as a coset space ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)/{\rm SO}_2(\mathbf R)$.  This is the first step in generalizing concepts defined initially on the upper half-plane (*e.g.*, modular forms as functions on the upper half-plane) to other settings by using coset or double coset spaces of other groups.

Quite generally, being able to think of certain constructions as orbits for a group action can give important insights.

1. Geometry: spheres are orbits for the orthogonal group acting on $\mathbf R^n$.  This leads to the general idea that "homogeneous spaces" of all kinds are orbits for the action of a Lie group on a space.
2. Algebra: all the roots of a polynomial (technically, of a separable polynomial) are the orbit for a Galois group acting on a suitable field extension.
3. Algebraic geometry: a "point" on a variety over a non-algebraically closed field is an orbit for the Galois group over the field of its algebraic closure. For example, the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ viewed over $\mathbf R$ has in addition to its classical real points on the curve some additional points such as $\{(\sqrt{2},i),(\sqrt{2},-i)\}$ of "degree $2$" that are an orbit for ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ acting on complex solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2=1$; the classical points have degree $1$.  These additional points correspond to something concrete about the ring $A = \mathbf R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$: its maximal ideals are all of the form
   $$
   \mathfrak m_{a,b} := \{f(x,y) \bmod x^2+y^2-1 : f(x,y) \in \mathbf R[x,y], f(a,b) = 0\}
   $$
   for each point $(a,b) \in \mathbf C^2$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, but $(a,b)$ and its conjugate point $(\overline{a},\overline{b})$, which is different from $(a,b)$ if $a$ or $b$ is not real, define the same maximal ideal.  Even a curve over $\mathbf R$ like $x^2 + y^2 = -1$, which classically looks like the empty set, is *not* empty: it has real points but none of degree $1$.  For instance, $\{(i,0),(-i,0)\}$ is a real point on this curve of degree $2$.  This corresponds to the fact that $\mathbf R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$
   has maximal ideals
   $$
   \mathfrak m_{a,b} := \{f(x,y) \bmod x^2+y^2+1 : f(x,y) \in \mathbf R[x,y], f(a,b) = 0\}
   $$
   for each $(a,b) \in \mathbf C^2$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = -1$, with points in the same orbit of ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ corresponding to the same maximal ideal.  The curve $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ has no real solutions, but $\mathbf R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$ has maximal ideals, and those correspond to orbits of ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ on the complex solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = -1$.
4. Number theory: Galois groups act on the ideals in the ring of integers of a number field, and the fact that all prime ideals lying over a given prime number form a single orbit for this action is really, really important in number theory.
5. Number theory again: you can create all primitive Pythagorean triples from the single triple $(3,4,5)$ by applying the integral orthogonal group of $x^2+y^2 - z^2$ to $(3,4,5)$. See [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/descentPythag.pdf.).  More generally, the orbits for that group on the set of integral solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ are the solutions with a common gcd for the three coordinates.
6. Number theory again: for a field $K$, ${\rm GL}_2(K)$ acts on $K \cup \{\infty\}$ by  $(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})\cdot z = (az+b)/(cz+d)$ $(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})\cdot \infty = a/c$ if $c \not= 0$ and the value is $\infty$ if $c = 0$. (It would be cleaner to act on ${\mathbf P}^1(K)$ by $(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})\cdot [x:y] = [ax+by:cx+dy]$.) That ${\rm GL}_2(K)$ has a single orbit on $K \cup \{\infty\}$ is not very interesting. If $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbf Q$ and we use the subgroup ${\rm SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$, its action on $K \cup \{\infty\}$ has finitely many orbits, which correspond to the ideal classes of the ideal class group of $K$. To a number theorist, those ideal classes are interesting. For example, $K \cup \{\infty\}$ is a single orbit for ${\rm SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$ if and only if $\mathcal O_K$ has unique factorization.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the points $(\pm i,1)$ aren't on the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ when we admit complex solutions.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz I corrected that miscalculation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to note:

1. The group acts transitively within an orbit
2. an orbit is a special form of fixed subset under an action.
3. It's sort of an analogue to cosets.

It's like you are stratifying the set into nice pieces that the group operates on individually.

Suppose you were studying the action of 3-d rotations which fix the Earth's axis. The orbits are what you'd call "latitudes."

Comment: To follow up on point 3, they really are closely related. In particular the cosets $G/H$ are the orbits of $H$ equipped with the $G$-set structure $g \cdot h \mapsto gh$.

Comment: To follow up on @CharlesHudgins' comment: And moreover, every orbit looks like this (has isomorphic action): if the stabilizer of a point $x$ is $H$, then the action of $G$ on the orbit containing $x$ is isomorphic to the action on $G/H$.